# Postman: Invalid CORS Request

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, http, development, postman

I use Postman to make manual requests to a REST API my team develops.

I recently added an `Origin` header to an OPTIONS request in order to test whether CORS response headers are sent properly.

Ever since, for every request I make, I get an error status `403 Forbidden` and a message `Invalid CORS request`.

Most of the same requests works completely fine with cURL, therefore I do not think that it is a server-side problem.

What does Postman want and how do I fix this?

Comment: This seems to be a programming question. You may have more luck asking on [so].